# How to be memory-efficient with variables in classes?

Tags: python, class, memory, memory-management, dictionary

Suppose, for the sake of example, that I have a class like this:

```
def class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def lookup(self):
        return dict[x]
```

The purpose of the `lookup` function is to look up `x` in a dict and return the value. Suppose that this dict is very large. I am wondering whether to declare the dict in the class, or whether to declare the dict as a global variable.

I am worried about memory-efficiency: the dict is going to be constant, and I want it not to take more memory than it would need. Thus, I am asking about how classes use memory. If I declare e.g. 50,000 instances of `Foo`, and I declare the dict within `Foo`, does that mean I am spawning 50,000 copies of `Foo`? Whereas if I refer to the dict as a global variable, I will not spawn any additional copies?

How do I make as few copies of the dict as possible? Ideally, this program would have just one.

Comment: http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: @Andreas Yes, the two instances of `Foo` in memory are distinct -- but are the methods on these objects also distinct? I don't see why the same function (`lookup`) would be copied every time. It would be most efficient to just maintain a pointer to the `lookup` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should have `dict` as global variable. The idea of inner variables is that you can change and use them independently without clashes. That's why every instance of `Foo` would have it's own copy of dict. (Actually named `self.dict` - like you should have `self.x` as an argument in your `lookup`function which uses object's inner variable.) Using global variable both saves memory and prevents the possibility that there might be different versions of dict in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Every object has a dict inherently, if you wish to be memory efficient you have a single object that stores all 50k rather than 50k objects.

If you have a data store object which takes a name, or possibly and index, as a parameter for for `get` as well as a value for `set` you will only have one dictionary which will store all your values.  Of course if you use `setattr(self, name, value)` in your set method it will allow you to access the values as `obj.name` - the only thing is that python already does that for you.

```
In [4]: class DS(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [5]: ds = DS()

In [6]: ds.a = 'A'

In [7]: ds.b = 2

In [8]: ds
Out[8]: <__main__.DS at 0x3c82db0>

In [9]: ds.a
Out[9]: 'A'

In [10]: ds.b
Out[10]: 2

In [11]: dir(ds)
Out[11]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'a',
 'b']
```

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer? This is so brief as to be marginally unclear. While I think I understand, I'd just like this answer to also be useful to others.